# Calculate projection of a line in a square

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, transformation, 3d

Said that we have two points (P1, P2) that form a line, and 3 points (S1,S2,S3) that form a triangle, how would we calculate the position X and Y of the point resulting from the intersection of the line and the plane containing the triangle?

[image: SPACE]

Comment: @Anhad Please feel free to restore your original in case.. I included extended parts of the plane containing the triangle for line to pierce..

Answer (score 0):

in the 3D-coordinate system (x,y,z):

- write the line that joins $p_1p_2$
- find the point of this line with $z$-coordinate $=0$ (intersection with your plane)
- done

Comment: Hi there! I think I didn't explain myself correctly. That's not the solution because the point S1 is not in the center (0,0,0). The square can be anywhere in the 3d space, and I need to find the intersection point, and get its coordinates INSIDE the square, not inside the 3d space.

Comment: @NathanParker do you have information about $p_1$ and $p_2$ (you should do)? , then what prohibit you from transforming those information into coordinates in the system where $s_1$ is the origin ?

Comment: then how could i do that?